# Reason of wakeup from Standby mode in STM32F4

Tags: stm32f4

I need to know what was the reason for wakeup from standby mode in STM32F4.
I'm using both the WKUP pin (PA0) and the RTC wakeup interrupt asnd I need to know upon wakeup what was the reason.

Thanks.

Comment: Try checking if the RTC Wakeup (WUTF) flag is set.

Comment: the problem is that i need to know if WKUP pin was the reason also! maybe I need to rephrase my question to - is there an indication that WKUP pin was the reason for wakeup ?

Comment: If it was not the RTC then it was the WKUP pin, isn't that true? So if the WUF flag is set which means  Power Wake Up but the WUTF flag is not then it was not the RTC that initiated the wake-up.

Comment: well consider the situation that WKUP pin was the reason of wakeup and just before checking the RTC_WUTF we get an RTC WAKEUP interrupt! in this case we will miss the WKUP pin interrupt.

Comment: Well yes, that can be a problem. I do not know about any status bit connected to the WKUP pin. Maybe you could try to disable the RTC interrupt as soon as possible in case of wakeups. But you should contact ST Microelectronics about your problem, maybe they can help you.